# getTransactionReceipt() return None

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js

`w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)` function returns `None`.

My code:

```
provider = HTTPProvider('http://0.0.0.0:9945')
w3 = Web3(provider)

contract = w3.eth.contract(contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])

tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3.eth.coinbase, 'gas': 250000})

print (tx_hash)
time.sleep(1)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
print (tx_receipt)
contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
```

`tx_hash` is normal value but `tx_receipt` is `None`.

So my error:

```
contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What client are you connecting to at 9945?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make the code readable for others. Please format the code yourself next time (using the Code button on toolbar or Ctrl+K) before you post the question.

Comment: 9945 is my local geth server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that because you used the variable name `w3`, you are using [web3.py](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py). The [getTransactionReceipt docs](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getTransactionReceipt) say:

> If the transaction has not yet been mined, returns `None`

So `sleep(1)` wasn't sufficient to wait for the next block to be mined.

Solving the problem will depend on what kind of client you're connecting to, and what its settings are. For example, If it's something like `geth`, you may need to turn on `--mine` to start mining blocks.  You will probably have luck finding answers on generating blocks for a particular client at the [Ethereum StackExchange site](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/), once you can share your client and configuration.

Comment: Thank you I solved this problem using                      (      while w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash) is None:)